# Division between data in rows - SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The data in my table looks like this:

```
date, app, country, sales
2017-01-01,XYZ,US,10000
2017-01-01,XYZ,GB,2000
2017-01-02,XYZ,US,30000
2017-01-02,XYZ,GB,1000
```

I need to find, for each app on a daily basis, the ratio of US sales to GB sales, so ideally the result would look like this:

```
date, app, ratio
2017-01-01,XYZ,10000/2000 = 5
2017-01-02,XYZ,30000/1000 = 30
```

I'm currently dumping everything into a csv and doing my calculations offline in Python but I wanted to move everything onto the SQL side. One option would be to aggregate each country into a subquery, join and then divide, such as

```
select d1_us.date, d1_us.app, d1_us.sales / d1_gb.sales from
(select date, app, sales from table where date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-10' and country = 'US') as d1_us
join 
(select date, app, sales from table where date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-10' and country = 'GB') as d1_gb
on d1_us.app = d1_gb.app and d1_us.date = d1_gb.date
```

Is there a less messy way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the ratio of SUM(CASE WHEN) and GROUP BY in your query to do this without requiring a subquery.

```
SELECT DATE, 
       APP,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'GB' THEN SALES END) AS RATIO    
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DATE, APP;
```

Based on the likelihood of the GB sales being zero, you can tweak the GB's ELSE condition, maybe `ELSE 1`, to avoid Divide by zero error. It really depends on how you want to handle exceptions.

Comment: dont you need the `ELSE 0` for second case?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Not at all.  That formulation is how you avoid divide-by-zero.

Comment: The current formulation would evaluate the denominator to NULL if there is no GB data which will ultimately evaluate the entire expression to NULL. Without throwing divide-by-zero error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one query with grouping and provide the condition once:

```
SELECT date, app,
       SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN SALES END) AS ratio
WHERE date between '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-10'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, app;
```

However, this gives you zero if there are no records for US and `NULL` if there are no records for GB. If you need to return different values for those cases, you can use another `CASE WHEN` surrounding the division. For example, to return -1 and -2 respectively, you can use:

```
SELECT date, app,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN -1
            WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN -2
            ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END) /
                 SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN SALES END)
            END AS ratio
WHERE date between '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-10'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, app;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (
  date DATE,
  app VARCHAR(5),
  country VARCHAR(5),
  sales DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
  ('2017-01-01','XYZ','US',10000),
  ('2017-01-01','XYZ','GB',2000),
  ('2017-01-02','XYZ','US',30000),
  ('2017-01-02','XYZ','GB',1000);


WITH q AS (
    SELECT
      date,
      app,
      country,
      SUM(sales) AS sales
    FROM t
    GROUP BY date, app, country
) SELECT
    q1.date,
    q1.app,
    q1.country || ' vs ' || NVL(q2.country,'-') AS ratio_between,
    CASE WHEN q2.sales IS NULL OR q2.sales = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(q1.sales / q2.sales, 2) END AS ratio
  FROM q AS q1
    LEFT JOIN q AS q2 ON q2.date = q1.date AND
                    q2.app = q1.app AND
                    q2.country != q1.country
  -- WHERE q1.country = 'US'
  ORDER BY q1.date;
```

**Results for any country vs any country (WHERE q1.country='US' is commented out)**

```
date,app,ratio_between,ratio
2017-01-01,XYZ,GB vs US,0.20
2017-01-01,XYZ,US vs GB,5.00
2017-01-02,XYZ,GB vs US,0.03
2017-01-02,XYZ,US vs GB,30.00
```

**Results for US vs any other country (WHERE q1.country='US' uncommented)**

```
date,app,ratio_between,ratio
2017-01-01,XYZ,US vs GB,5.00
2017-01-02,XYZ,US vs GB,30.00
```

The trick is in JOIN clause.
Results of a subquery q which aggregates data by date, app and country are joined with results themselves but on date and app.

This way, for every date, app and country we get a "match" with any another country on same date and app. By adding q1.country != q2.country, we exclude results for same country, highlighted below with *

```
date,app,country,sales,date,app,country,sales
*2017-01-01,XYZ,GB,2000.00,2017-01-01,XYZ,GB,2000.00*
2017-01-01,XYZ,GB,2000.00,2017-01-01,XYZ,US,10000.00
2017-01-01,XYZ,US,10000.00,2017-01-01,XYZ,GB,2000.00
*2017-01-01,XYZ,US,10000.00,2017-01-01,XYZ,US,10000.00*
2017-01-02,XYZ,GB,1000.00,2017-01-02,XYZ,US,30000.00
*2017-01-02,XYZ,GB,1000.00,2017-01-02,XYZ,GB,1000.00*
*2017-01-02,XYZ,US,30000.00,2017-01-02,XYZ,US,30000.00*
2017-01-02,XYZ,US,30000.00,2017-01-02,XYZ,GB,1000.00
```